# I get a Elasticsearch connection error: errno 61 since today. It worked all fine, and suddenly my elastic search terminal shows weird things

Tags: python, elasticsearch, errno

**I get the following error:**
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x12c9b1cc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61]

**And this is shown by my elastic search terminal, which is different than yesterday. It worked before. Could someone please help me:**

Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsException: Failed to load settings from [elasticsearch.yml]
at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1194)
at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.loadConfigWithSubstitutions(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:126)
at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:52)
at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:110)
at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.xcontent.XContentParseException: [110:20] mapping values are not allowed here
in 'reader', line 110, column 20:
verification_mode: certificate
^

at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 110, column: 20]
at org.elasticsearch.xcontent.provider.json.JsonXContentParser.newXContentParseException(JsonXContentParser.java:52)
at org.elasticsearch.xcontent.provider.json.JsonXContentParser.nextFieldName(JsonXContentParser.java:71)
at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.fromXContent(Settings.java:719)
at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.fromXContent(Settings.java:687)
at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1190)
... 7 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException: mapping values are not allowed here
in 'reader', line 110, column 20:
verification_mode: certificate
^

at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 110, column: 20]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException.from(MarkedYAMLException.java:28)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:407)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.nextFieldName(JsonParser.java:1038)
at org.elasticsearch.xcontent.provider.json.JsonXContentParser.nextFieldName(JsonXContentParser.java:69)
... 10 more
Caused by: mapping values are not allowed here
in 'reader', line 110, column 20:
verification_mode: certificate
^

```
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:910)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:400)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:251)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:628)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:166)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:176)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:403)
... 12 more
```

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Proces voltooid]

Comment: Hi Esmee.. your client application is not able to open a connection to Elasticsearch, because it is not running. Elasticsearch is not able to start because you have an invalid YAML as configuration file. Could you verify that your elasticsearch.yml file is a valid YAML? In particular the verification_mode setting

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reaction. Yes, I just found out that when my laptop restarts, it changes two letters in the config yml to capital letters. Changed it and it works again!